# Show $f: S^1 - {N} \to \mathbb{R} $ $f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_1}{1-x_2}$ is Homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

$S^1$ is a unit circle and $N := \{ (0,1) \in S^1\}$. The question hints that the for any $(x_1,x_2) \in S^1- {N}$, line joining
$N$
and
$(
x_
1
, x_
2
)$
meets the
$x$
-axis at
($f
(
x_
1
;x_
2
)
, 0
)$

However, I'm not sure I understand the hints at all. Since I draw a unit circle picture, if I choose a point above the $x$-axis, then the adjoin line doesn't intersect $x$-axis at all. I can't see why this helps to show that title function is homeomorphism

Comment: Your picture is incorrectly drawn.  My first guess is that you've drawn the bounded line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(x_1,x_2)$, which does not intersect the $x$-axis if $x_2>0$.  A _line_ is not bounded. The line through $(0,1)$ and a point $(x_2,x_2)$ satisfying $x_2^2+x_2^2=1$ and $x_2\ne 1$ does intersect the $x$-axis. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: oh, I see. However, why is helps me to solve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your picture is incorrectly drawn.  My first guess is that you've drawn the bounded line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(x_1,x_2)$, which does not intersect the $x$-axis if $x_2>0$.  A *line* is not bounded. The line through $(0,1)$ and a point $(x_2,x_2)$ satisfying $x_2^2+x_2^2=1$ and $x_2\ne 1$ does intersect the $x$-axis.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)

The equation of any non-vertical line passing through $(0,1)$ is $(y-1)=m(x-0)$.  In this case the slope is $m=\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \dfrac{x_2-1}{x_1-0}$.

The problem now is to find the $x$-intercept of the line, which is the value of $x$ when $y=0$.

Comment: sorry, for the late reply. However, I'm stuck on how to find its inverse function (or show inverse continuous). I tried to define $g: (0, 2\pi) \to \mathbb{R^2}, f(x) = (sin(x), cos(x))$ Also, need to show $(fg)^{-1} g= f$ so $f^{-1}$ can be written as a composition of continuous function. But this case I have to show $g^{-1}$ continuous, and I couldn't find its inverse function

Comment: Finding the inverse function is finding $x_1,x_2$ satisfying $x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1$ and $x = \dfrac{x_1}{1-x_2}$. Solving the second equation from $x_1$, you get $x_1 = x(1-x_2)$. Plugging that into the first equation in place of $x_1$, you get $x^2(1-x_2)^2 + x_2^2=1$. Collecting $x_2$, that becomes $x_2^2(x^2+1) -2x^2 x_2 +x^2-1=0$. You have a quadratic equation in $x_2$. And you know in advance that one of the solutions is $x_2=1$, i.e. the point $(0,1)$ is one of the two points on the intersection of that line and that circle.  So you should be able to factor the quadratic polynomial as$\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$ $(x_1-1)(\cdots\cdots\cdots)$.  Do long division and get $(x_2-1)\Big( x_2(x^2+1) + (1-x^2) \Big)$.  Setting that second factor to $0$ and solving, in order to get the solution other than $x_2=1$, we get $x_2 = \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}$.  Then we need to find $x_1$.  We found it is $x(1-x_2)$, so it's $x\left( 1- \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1} \right) = \dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}$.  So we have $(x_1,x_2) = \left( \dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}, \dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1} \right)$.  That's the inverse function. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** A line is does not have end points , that is it is not bounded . Therefore your picture is wrong.

Also you can see that it cuts the $x$-axis at the point $(f(x_1,x_2),0)$, That means for every point in $S^1-N$ we have a point in $\Bbb{R}$. A clue for your homeomorphism (Why?)

Comment: is it necessary to find explicit function of inverse of $f$  to show that $f$ has continuous inverse function ?

Comment: Yes it is @Hobbit6094

Comment: I was thinking if there is some theorem or manipulation of composition to show its inverse continuous. Finding its explicit function of inverse, then use definition of continuity to prove seems bit lot work